# VBA Code Macro to input user name and password in coding so that macro itself logsin to the data base

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am very new to VBA Macro and access... I have created a macro that exports data from access to excel file. Now my access database needs a user name and password every time to execute any table or query. So when I run the macro it also asks for the user name and password to execute further, hence I want to input user name and password in the code itself so upon executing/running a macro itself input the username and password. I have code like this below but it does not work... Please help me.......

[image: Macro should automatically input the user name and password in this]

Below is my code: -

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wbtarget As Workbook
Dim FinalExp As QueryDef
Dim rsFinalExp As Recordset
Dim arrFound As Variant, arrReplace As Variant
Dim i As Long

Dim Username_List As Variant
Dim Passoword_List As Variant
Dim Username As String
Dim Password As String

'Extract from Access Database

Set FinalExp = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("FinalExp")

Username = "QWERT"
Password = "TREWQ@1"

Set rsFinalExp = FinalExp.OpenRecordset()

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


'Export to Excel

Set wbtarget = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:DestinationPath.xlsm")
Set ws = wbtarget.Worksheets("Sample File")


ws.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsFinalExp

'Further modification in excel

arrFound = Array("A", "B", "C")
    arrReplace = Array("Ok", "Deal", "Run")
    
    With ws
    
        For i = LBound(arrFound) To UBound(arrFound)
            .Range("B:B").Replace what:=arrFound(i), Replacement:=arrReplace(i), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next i
        
    End With


wbtarget.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to access a DB2 database. Did you try saving the password while creating the link to the DB2 tables? Or via DSN?

Comment: Sounds like `FinalExp` is a [pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42). Incorporate credentials in its connection.

Comment: FinalExp is a query name ... DB2 database it asks for user name and pwd every time when login